# code to print sum of n natural no. doesnt work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and don't know why this code doesn't work to print sum of n natural numbers. I have tried with for l in range and also while, it works with them but using if else doesn't seem to provide a result. Please help me with this.

[image]

Text form:

```py
l=1
n=int(input("n="))
sum=0
if l<=n:
    sum=sum+l
    l=1+l
else:
    print(sum)
```

Comment: Please post your code as text and not images. We cannot copy code and reproduce the problem if there is an image.

Comment: Yes, because when you do ```for i in range(n)```. The ```range()``` function returns a sequence of numbers, starting from 0 by default. When you don't use that, you are just adding ```l``` to ```sum```.What do you expect?

Comment: Do not use python keywords like `sum` as variables. This would not have caused a problem but it is good practice to not use such names

Answer (score 1):

`if` doesn't provide a result because it executes only once when the given condition satisfies. `if` is **not a loop control structure** like `for`, `while`.

So if you want to avoid loops (`for` and `while`) you can use the formula.

> **Sum of first n natural numbers = `(n * (n+1))//2`**

*Do not use any python reserved keywords as variable names. **sum** in your code.*

Code with formula:

```
n = int(input('n: '))
sums = ((n * (n + 1))//2

print(sums)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks if `l<=n` and adds `l` to `sum` if `True`, then the program **ends**.
So you should replace `if` with `while` and remove the `else`:
BTW:

- python supports `+=` operators and it's better to be *explicit* that you are increacmenting.
- As others have mentioned, it's not good habits to use the name of a build-in function as the name of a variable.

Final code:

```py
l=1
n=int(input("n="))
ans=0
while l<=n:
    ans+=l
    l+=1
print(ans)
```

or,better yet,use `for` loops:

```py
n=int(input("n="))
ans=0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    ans+=i
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop.

In your code, there is no loop. So what it does, it checks if `l` is less than or equal to `n`. Then, if it evaluates to `True`, it sums `sum` and `l`. But now, it exits the program because no loop was there.

```
n=int(input("n="))
su=0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    su+=i
print(su)
```

Or a more squeezed code, using the built in `sum`

```
su=sum(i for i in range(1,n+1))
```